# How does cocos2d-x compile command set SDKVersion for Android Studio project?

Tags: cocos2d-x

So I want to compile my cocos2d-x project for Android Studio using cmd with:

`cocos compile -p android --android-studio --ap android-22`

I found the description about `--ap` option in the wiki : `Specify the API-Level of android sdk. Console will auto select it if not specified.` .

**My question is that:**

1. Is this API `compiledSDKVersion` or `minSDKVersion` or `targetSDKVersion`? And how do I set those SDKVersion in above command ?
2. If I want to change those `SDKVersion` , could I just **edit build.Gradle(Module:MyApp) and build.Gradle(Module:libcocos2dx) then Sync Gradle** or I have to **recompile using the cmd** with above command?

   Your attention and help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. targetSDKVersion , `targetSDKVersion` is provided by `project.properties` file .  If you're using Android Studio then you can set `compileSdkVersion` and `minSdkVersion` inside build.gradle file.
2. If you need to change in targetSDKVersion change in `project.properties`. I'll recommend not to change targetSDKVersion.